# What is reverse induction?

Tags: soft-question, induction, terminology

I was reading the theorem, then I got this term. I know about simple induction but don't have any idea about reverse induction.

See the image:
[image]

> Question : What is reverse induction ?

Comment: Where does this come from? I think there are more terminology here that I'm not familiar with. Specifically what is $\mathfrak H$, what does $[k]$ mean and what is $\operatorname{pr}_\mathfrak L$? What do they mean by "split"?

Comment: See [Reverse induction](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Mathematical_Proof/Methods_of_Proof/Proof_by_Induction#Reverse_Induction).

Comment: @skyking sorry my question is not how to prove theorem7.2, but in general what it meant by reverse induction.

Comment: @sssss Yes. I understand that, but my comment was a hint that a bit more context would be useful. Note that the same term may have different meaning in different contexts, also one sometimes can deduce the meaning of words from it's context. That is knowing the context where this theorem was presented could be useful as well as the other terminology that is used in that context.