# Can A reverse induction exist?

Tags: logic, induction

I am calling this reverse induction as I don't know if this is the right term, I've read these posts
[Proving a statement false by reverse induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2731867/proving-a-statement-false-by-reverse-induction)
[What is reverse induction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2470196/what-is-reverse-induction)

However they are not quite what I have in mind, my question is:

Is it valid to prove by induction that if $P(k)$ is wrong and then proving that $P(k+1)$ is wrong also (using the induction hypothesis) - then $P(n)$ is false for any $n \geq k \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Let's say we have a statement that any number $2k+1$ is not divisible by $2$ then, for $P(k=1)$ we have that $3$ which is not divisible by $2$ of course, then assuming that $2k+1$ - then proving that $(2(k+1) + 1)$ is not divisible by $2$ also - so we have proven that any number of the form $2k+1$ is not divisible by $2$. - Is it valid? (Just an example)

Is it a valid argument to say that the statement is congruent to: Any number $2k$ is divisible by $2$ ?
I  don't think it is logical to assume that... but again, I am not sure at all.. because who said they are the complementary statements of one another?

Thank you!

Comment: The induction principle of course applies also to a false statement. Hence, yes , this is a valid proof. In the given example, an integer is either of the form $2k$ or of the form $2k+1$, hence in this case, we could prove the claim this way because in usual logic , we have the principle of the excluded middle.

Answer (score 2):

Note that saying that $P(k)$ is "wrong" (aka false) is the same as stating that its negation $\neg P(k)$ is true (assuming that you work with [excluded middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle)), so setting $Q(k)$ to be $\neg P(k)$ gives you usual induction.